# GLSL bypassing float array to uniform

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

setShaders

```
    muOffsetHandle = getUniformLocation("offset");      
    muWeightHandle = getUniformLocation("weight");
```

useProgram

```
    GLES20.glUniform1fv(muOffsetHandle, 1, mOffset, 0);
    GLES20.glUniform1fv(muWeightHandle, 1, mWeight, 0);
```

vars

```
private int muOffsetHandle;
private int muWeightHandle;

protected float mOffset[] =new float[] {0.0f, 1.3f, 3.3f}; 
protected float mWeight[] =new float[] {0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f};
```

FragmentShader

```
        "uniform float offset[3];\n" +
        "uniform float weight[3];\n" +
```

then trying to reach: weight[i]

I get this:

Shader log: 0:13: S0004: Member reference or swizzle attempted on non-structure and non-vector

line 13: `tc += texture2D(uFrameBufferTexture, vTextureCoord[0].xy + vec2(0.0, offset[i])/uScreenHeight).rgb * weight[i];`

(i = 0 to 2)

so my question: How to bypassing a float array to a uniform? float[3]

the code

```
protected static final String mFShader = 
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
        "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
        "uniform float uTime;\n" +
        "uniform float uScreenWidth;\n" +
        "uniform float uScreenHeight;\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D uFrameBufferTexture;\n"+

        "uniform float offset[3];\n" +
        "uniform float weight[3];\n" +

        "void main() {\n"+
        "  vec3 tc = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);\n"+
        "  if (vTextureCoord[0].x<(uTime-0.01)) {\n"+
        "    tc = texture2D(uFrameBufferTexture, vTextureCoord[0].xy).rgb * weight[0];\n"+
        "    for (int i=1; i<3; i++) {\n"+
        "      tc += texture2D(uFrameBufferTexture, vTextureCoord[0].xy + vec2(0.0, offset[i])/uScreenHeight).rgb * weight[i];\n"+
        "      tc += texture2D(uFrameBufferTexture, vTextureCoord[0].xy - vec2(0.0, offset[i])/uScreenHeight).rgb * weight[i];\n"+
        "    }\n"+
        "  }\n"+
        "  else if (vTextureCoord[0].x>=(uTime+0.01)) {\n"+
        "    tc = texture2D(uFrameBufferTexture, vTextureCoord[0].xy).rgb;\n"+
        "  }\n"+
        "   gl_FragColor = vec4(tc, 1.0);\n"+
        "}\n";
```

Comment: Can we see the line that's actually causing the error?

Comment: tc += texture2D(uFrameBufferTexture, vTextureCoord[0].xy + vec2(0.0, offset[i])/uScreenHeight).rgb * weight[i];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't actually with `weight` or `offset`. The compiler is complaining that you say `vTextureCoord[0].xy`, but you declared `vTextureCoord` as `varying vec2 vTextureCoord;`.

Either declare `vTextureCoord` as an array, or don't say `[0]`.

Comment: `varying vec2 vTextureCoord[1];` (or whatever you need instead of 1)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare it as an array, but if you want you can simply use:

```
varying vec4 vTextureCoord[3]; // you can use anything you want between the brackets
```

Also, don't forget to modify the varying the the vertex shader too so that they will be identical.